# I keep getting this the IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thats my code below, i am quite new so i am sure its just an amateur mistake on my side

```
def availability():
    r = requests.get('https://planet54.com/products/strappy-casual-dress-black.json')
    blackdress =json.loads((r.text))['product']['title']
    productname = blackdress

      for blackdress in productname:

       if productname == 'Strappy Casual Dress - Black':
            producturl = 'https://planet54.com/products/strappy-casual-dress-black'

          return producturl

    return False
```

Comment: python uses indentation to define code blocks. there for you cant mix and match your indentation it needs to be consistent

Comment: Your for loop is indented for no reason it seems.

Comment: Also the indentation inside the `if` statement is inconsistent.

Comment: Also your first return is positioned improperly according to the statement in the if block. Python relies on proper indents to avoid using { } or end if statements as in other languages. If you don't have proper indents, Python has no idea what to do with your code. On that note, I assume you want to check every single product name and see if it matches the condition you posed in the if statement. If so, check my answer.

Comment: I recommend (1) taking a look at the [PEP8 docs on Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), (2) using an editor or an IDE that detects and displays possible indentation errors on your code (even before you run it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you want.

```
def availability():
  r = requests.get('https://planet54.com/products/strappy-casual-dress-black.json')
  blackdress =json.loads((r.text))['product']['title']
  productname = blackdress

  for blackdress in productname:
    if productname == 'Strappy Casual Dress - Black':
      producturl = 'https://planet54.com/products/strappy-casual-dress-black'
      return producturl

  return False
```

Although note that your return inside the if statement will cause the for-loop to quit early if the condition is found.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other languages where whitespace is ignored, it has a very specific function in python. Python language uses indentation to nest and define code structure and code blocks. So you need to ensure your indentation is consistent in your code.

```py
def availability():
    r = requests.get('https://planet54.com/products/strappy-casual-dress-black.json')
    blackdress = json.loads((r.text))['product']['title']
    productname = blackdress

    for blackdress in productname:
        if productname == 'Strappy Casual Dress - Black':
            producturl = 'https://planet54.com/products/strappy-casual-dress-black'
            return producturl
    return False
```

Comment: This will "return" after the first loop regardless of the condition. I don't think this is what OP wanted, they probably wanted to loop through the entire `productname` variable and see if ANY match a certain name, not just the first product.

Comment: Good spot. Indented the return inside the if